# Passing multiple classes ( Class<? extends foo> Interfaces and Abstract classes)

Tags: java, class, interface, extends

I'm developing a League of Legends plugin for Minecraft using the Bukkit API. Regardless of that, this question is universal. Since there are so many different characters in League of Legends, there's no telling which one a player may choose. So how in the world can I create a variable that can account for this?

So I've created the base interface that all character classes will implement:

```
public interface ChampInterface {

    void setUp(Core plugin);

    String getName();

    ItemStack getItem();

    void add(String name);

    int getID();

}
```

Following this, I have an abstract class that implements the ChampInterface:

```
public abstract class ChampTemplate implements ChampInterface{

    private String name;

    private int ID;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return ID;
    }

}
```

Finally, all characters would be created extending the abstract class, like so:

```
public class MasterYi extends ChampTemplate{

    Core plugin;

    private String name;

    private static List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MasterYi(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp(Core plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Master Yi";
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack getItem() {
        return new ItemStack(Material.WOOD_SWORD);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(String name) {
        players.add(name);
    }

}
```

(ignore the Core plugin)

Now every time a player joins the game, a PlayerInfo class is generated where all stats are stored. So once the player chooses a character, that class has to be passed to the player's PlayerInfo instance (for sake of making this simple, I put the passed class in the constructor):

```
public class PlayerInfo {

    private Class<? extends ChampTemplate> champ;

    private String name;

    public PlayerInfo(String name, Class<? extends ChampTemplate> c){
        this.champ = c;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        //somehow say champ.getName()   and it would reference the appropriate class
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now we can finally get to my question. I have declared the variable "champ" as the type Class, however, whenever I want to call the abstract method of getID() from the MasterYi class, that option doesn't appear in the dropdown list when I write "champ.". So how can I make the variable "champ" be able to access all the abstract and interface methods no matter what character class I send it?

Thanks for bearing with me through this long post and thanks for any insight or advice! :)

Comment: You can't call `getID` method on an object of type `Class`. You can call `getID` on an object of type `ChampTemplate`. If you want to be able to access the champ's id from `PlayerInfo` pass a `ChampTemplate` to it rather than a Class. eg:- `public PlayerInfo(String name, ChampTemplate c)`

Comment: I'm fairly certain you don't need generics for this. All subclasses can be stored in a superclass reference variable and their methods can be called by doing `superClassVariable.methodName`. Also what is the reasoning behind `private String name` in the Master Yi class? It currently looks like a useless field. Same for `name` in PlayerInfo.

Answer (score 2):

Since `MasterYi` extends `ChampTemplate`, it can be used as a replacement for it. Meaning you don't have to check if it extends it.

```
private ChampTemplate champ;

public PlayerInfo(String name, ChampTemplate champ){
    this.champ = champ;
}

public String getName(){
    return champ.getName();
}
```

Then when you want to make a `PlayerInfo` object, you can pass in the `MasterYi` object.

```
MasterYi my = new MasterYi("Test");

PlayerInfo pi = new PlayerInfo("Bob", my);
```

And you can get the name of the champion from the `MasterYi` object, as it is overridden.

```
pi.getName(); //Returns "Master Yi"
```

So really, you don't have to check for anything. Just store a `ChampTemplate` and pass in whatever object you have that extends it.

**Edit: Using interfaces for what they are.**
Instead of making an interface, then having an abstract class implement that interface, then having another class finally extend that one, you can just implement the interface into your main class.

```
public interface IChampion {

    void setUp(Core plugin);

    String getName();

    ItemStack getItem();

    void add(String name);

    int getID();

}
```

Then have your `MasterYi` (or whatever other champions you add) implement that interface.

```
public class MasterYi implements IChampion{

    Core plugin;

    private String name;

    private static List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MasterYi(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUp(Core plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "Master Yi";
    }

    public ItemStack getItem() {
        return new ItemStack(Material.WOOD_SWORD);
    }

    public void add(String name) {
        players.add(name);
    }

}
```

And now you don't have an abstract class!

And to use the fix above, just replace all the `ChampTemplate`s with your interface.

```
private IChampion champ;

public PlayerInfo(String name, IChampion champ){
    this.champ = champ;
}

public String getName(){
    return champ.getName();
}
```

And getting the name still works!

Comment: Perfect! I came from C++ so I wasn't too sure how to translate this over from that language. This is exactly what I was looking for! :D